# alternatives to strcpy in ISO C89

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, ansi-c

I have to write a function for a phonebook.
I have defined the phonebook as an array of struct "contacts",each struct contact containing the name[],surname[],number,[]address[] strings,which are also the parameters of the function.
The problem is that when I have to save the entered parameters in the position "count"  of the phonebook array(i.e. phonebook[count].name) 
VS 2010 said I can't use "=" to save the string into the array.
On the internet some people said that I can use pointers or strcpy,but my teacher doesn't want me to use them.
Are there some alternatives?
I have to code in ISO C89(ANSI C) and I can use the string.h and ctype.h libraries (I can't use strcpy or strcat),and I can't use files or pointers.
I'm not sure about strncpy,anyway.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use [memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/), but most probably your teacher wants to copy the strings with a simple `for` loop.

Comment: I apologise for my ignorance, I'm completely new to coding.
How could I do it?

Comment: Use the force @Luke, use the [force](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Strings).

Comment: You can't use pointers, so you won't be able to use `memcpy` nor `strncpy`.

Comment: Just implement `strcpy`'s functionality yourself. It isn't hard. Just a single loop assigning the data character by character to the result will do it.

Comment: @MikeCAT `memcpy` and `strncpy` work with arrays as well.

Comment: @101010: They get a pointer, not an array. OP is supposed not to use pointers, so he cannot pass the arrays to any function. You cannot pass an array in C.

Comment: Restricing to C90 is simply a dumb constraint. It teaches problematic coding style at best best. That would be the same as a school teacher forcing his kids to talk in pidgin or any other restricted language. Possibly just because he cannot speak normal English.

Comment: @Olaf memcpy and strncpy work with arrays as well. The fact that passing an array to a function decays to a pointer doesn't mean that you are using pointers. At least not directly, from my point of view.

Comment: @101010: Well, that is **exactly** what it means. Try `void f(char a[]) { sizeof(a); }` (The same for a fixed-size array argument). You get the size of the pointer `a`, not that of he array. The C standard even clearly states that the array is **converted** to a pointer to the first element. Then try `void f(char (*a)[10]) { sizeof(*a); }`. Note this still passes a pointer, but to an array this time.

Comment: @Olaf I wouldn't be so sure, unless you are her/his teacher.

Comment: @101010: How would this be related? It is a matter of the [C standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note93).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple character-by-character assignment will work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFFER_LENGTH 128

struct contacts {
    char name[BUFFER_LENGTH];
    char surname[BUFFER_LENGTH];
    char number[BUFFER_LENGTH];
    char address[BUFFER_LENGTH];
};

int main(void) {
    struct contacts phonebook[1];
    int count = 0;
    char parameter[BUFFER_LENGTH];
    int i;

    /* enter some parameter */
    for (i = 0; i < BUFFER_LENGTH - 1; i++) {
        int input = getchar();
        if (input == '\n' || input == EOF) break;
        parameter[i] = input;
    }
    parameter[i] = '\0';

    /* save it to the array */
    for (i = 0;; i++) {
        if ((phonebook[count].name[i] = parameter[i]) == '\0') break;
    }

    /* print the saved parameter for checking */
    puts(phonebook[count].name);

    return 0;
}
```